# Diagonalizing operator over $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

I've been asked to diagonalise an operator on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, given by $Tf(z) = f(z^{-1}$). I know that I'm expected to find a $U$ such that $TU = UM_f$, where $M_f$ is the multiplication operator, however I can't seem to construct the $U$ that does this. Could anyone provide any hints?

Comment: look at the fourier series for f

Comment: Could you explain where I go from there? Perhaps it's just late and I'm a little foggy, but I can't work out how this changes my problem... =/

Comment: well, I was thinking that you could find all the eigenvalues directly.  This may not accord with your hint or instructions, but if $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n, f(\frac 1z) = \sum a_{-n} z^n$ and by inspection you get eigenfunctions $z^n + z^{-n}$ with eigenvalue 1, and $z^n - z^{-n}$ with eigenvalue -1.  They form a basis, so that's all.

Comment: Hmm, sure. I guess this is what I had anyway; the eigenvalues are easy to find since T^2 = I. I hacked out an attempt at finding U through Fourier series, and I _think_ I have that the corresponding multiplication operator is $e^{-inz}$ but I have no real clue about whether this is right.